# Using vNext Identity without using a database

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to implement a login system that has the users stored in a different database that I can't access and I can't save their passwords (company policy). I have a dll to validate the username and password.

I only store the username and the role in the app's database (along with other data).

How do I set up Identity to login users in this manner and also give them roles since membership and role providers no longer exist in vNext?

PS: I also want to only use the core framework if possible.

Comment: Don't use Identity, work directly with the dll. About roles, it should take you a day _at most_ to role your own stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `IPasswordValidator` (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/IPasswordValidator.cs) that reaches into your library and checks if user password is valid. Then this implementation plugs in to `UserManager.PasswordValidator`.

Comment: what about the rest? I don't want to use identity with a database and I want to define roles too. I am really bad at understanding identity so can you please explain in all possible details?

Comment: In this case I suggest you work your way through custom storage tutorials: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity and http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/01/20/implementing-asp-net-identity.aspx

Comment: Roles for users are provided by the system and are managed in `RoleManager` class in Identity

Comment: I looked at both of those posts already and they showcase Identity 2.0 and it doesn't fully apply to 3.0

Comment: Identity 3 is not released for production use yet - same as ASP.Net 6. So you won't find a lot of guidance on those. The principles are largely the same as in v2 branch and you have the source code for the framework.